# run Javascript three.j animation on performant machine/server but display it on a website, thus running also on not performant devices

Tags: javascript, three.js, server-side-rendering

I'll try my best to explain this as good as I can:

I have programmed an art installation (interactive animation with three.js), it is running very smooth on my laptop, but not on older machines and almost on no mobile devices. Is there any way to run the javascript animation on a performant machine/server but display/render it on a website, thus running also on not performant devices. I was thinking about something like done for CloudGaming (as in shadow.tech) or services like parsec.app maybe...

Any ideas/hints?

Answer (score 0):

I've thought about the same concept before too. The answer to your question rendering the three js on server and displaying it on an older machine will be something like this:

You are going to have to render three js on a server then basically live stream it to the client then capture the client's controls and send it back to the server to apply them but latency is going to be a pain in the ass so better write your code nice and neat and a lot of error handling. Come to think about it Google stadia does the same think too when you play games on youtube.

**Server Architecture**

So roughly thinking about it I would build my renderer backend like this:

First create a room with multiple instances of your three js code. => this basically means creating multiple (i.e index.js, index1.js, index2.js, etc...) Then Now decide if you wanna do this with the Straight Forward Recorded and Stream method or capture the stream directly from the canvas then broadcast it.

**Recorded and Stream method**

This means you create the js room then render and display it on the server machine then capture what is displaying on your screen using something like OBS studio then broadcast it to the client. I don't recommend this method.

OR

**captureStream() method**

After creating your room in your server run the three js code then access the canvas you are rendering the three js code in like this:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var video = document.querySelector('video');

// Optional frames per second argument.
var stream = canvas.captureStream(60);
// Set the source of the <video> element to be the stream from the <canvas>.
video.srcObject = stream;
```

Then use something like webrtc and broadcast it to the client.

This is an example site you can look at: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/canvas-pc/

***Honestly don't ditch the client interaction idea. Instead write code to detect latency before hand then decide to enable it for that specific client***

Hope this helps

Comment: hmm, yeah I was expecting latency problems, so for just displaying the animation on my website, I would be willing to sacrifice all interaction, and "fake" sensors and other inputs triggering changes... still the question remains, on what service and how could I pull this off?

Comment: So thars server architecture I will add an update to answer.

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: thanks! I totally get the part with .captureStream and webrtc, but I am struggling with "Server Architecture" - what kind of server/architecture is this? does it run on something like node.js, or is it some dedicated application where my html+three.js can run serverside, so that I can capture the stream and show it on my website?

Comment: node js is perfect for creating multiple rooms plus you can run three js on it so yeah go with node js. Watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktPz54wtzR8 to understand how to set up rooms so that you can run multiple instances of three js one server. The video is for creating video calls but you can easily figure out how to use it for three js once you get the concept. Feel free to comment if you have any other questions.

Comment: thanks so much so far! will do setup all and after some testing report back here. could take a while though...

Comment: Got u.nice coding :)